# Twig - Issue on a if statement with 2 conditions

Tags: html, twig

I'm getting a headache in front of a REALLY simple algorithm problem.

I want my anchor tag to be displayed every time **EXCEPT** once :

When 2 conditions are true --> **app.user.username == item.email AND 'delete' == action.name**

I did this so far :

```
{% if app.user.username == item.email and 'delete' == action.name  %}
           <a href="">...</a>
{% endif %}
```

In the above code, I do the opposite...

Here's what I need : 
[image]

What is the right combination to my need ?

Comment: so the current user can't delete himself, right?

Comment: that's what I need, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply `negate` the condition you posted, as example:

```
{% if not (app.user.username == item.email and 'delete' == action.name)  %}
```

you can test in [this working fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/hzi5mr)

Hope this help